# Rscript - Using same R-file, The R terminal behaves different compared to Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript

**Problem:** Using same R-file, The R terminal behaves different compared to Rstudio.

When running below R-file several times, in Rstudio I get the correct behaviour.

- First run [count=20], rest of run [count=1].

When running same R-file several times from a terminal, using [Rscript]:

- First run [count=20], rest of run [count=20].

**Wanted behaviour:**

I need the R terminal to behave same as R studio , creating counter with value [20] and for the rest of the times put it to value [1].

**My environment:**

Ubuntu Linux 18.04

R-studio: 1.1.453

Terminal (Bash 4.4.19, R v.3.4.4)

**Content of R-file:**

```
setwd ("/tmp-r") # Set working directory.

# Set [count] to 20 if [count] does not exists.
# Set [count] to 1 if [count] exists.
if (!exists('count')) {
  count <- 20
} else {
  count <- 1
}

save.image() # Save.
```

Comment: Somewhat obvious, but could it be that your global environment is contaminated after each consecutive run in RStudio? My point is, if you include `rm(list=ls()); gc(reset=TRUE)` at the very end of your R script, would it make the rest of run counter be equal to 20 in RStudio like it does in the terminal?

Comment: RStudio maintains the same session for each execution. Running Rscript loses the session between calls. You'd need to save the session (`save.image()` / `load()`) at the end and beginning of the script to keep the same state.

Comment: I perfomed some tests adding, [load('.Rdata'] at the beginning of the script. It adjust to the correct behaviour in R terminal. However, having the  [load] makes Rstudio always loading [value=1] which means I would have to "clean/reset" the count residing in [.RData] before running the script the first time. This for the script to capture that the variable [count] does not exist, thus creating the variable and set it to value [20].

Comment: @12b345b6b78 You are correct in a way that if adding [rm(list=ls()] and [gc(reset=TRUE)], Rstudio will behave same as R terminal, meaning that in Rstudio the value with be kept to [20] for all the script runs. - However, adding [load('.RData'] below the [rm(list=ls()] and [gc(reset=TRUE)], will make Rstudio behave correctly.

Comment: I discovered that even if the minified above code works, applying the solution to the expanded script does not work. When doing some tests, it seems that the local [.Rprofile] affect the total solution.

Answer (score 1):

With input from comments, I found 2 issues that solves the problem. Both for the minified test-script I published as a question, and my expanded script.

1) Add [load ('RData')], in the beginning since the load behaviour differs between Rstudio and R terminal. Rstudio dynamically update the global environment whenever you send in a change in the Rstudio console. R terminal loses the session between calls and therefor R terminal needs the R-file to start with [load ('RData')].

2) To solve my expanded script, I found out that the local [.Rprofile] has a [save.image('.RData)] at the end of the script. When removing that command in [.Rprofile] it solves the bigger script.